# Two different horizontal hr/separator in CSS

Tags: css, colors, separator

The CSS code of a separator is like this:

```
hr.separator {
    border: 0;height: 2px;background: #000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -o-lineargradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    width: 45%;
}
```

Where this is the markup:

```
<hr class="separator" />
```

I want to add another "hr" with different color. (left, #fff, #000, #fff).

Comment: Yes. Exactly! can you help please?

Comment: There must be a way to add another hr with different class style. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @TumajNuri http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/Lrwgkfey/ Check it

Comment: This is not a "write it for me" website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
hr.separator {
    border: 0;height: 2px;background: #000;
    width: 45%;
}
hr.separator.red{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);
    background-image: -o-lineargradient(left, #AA0000, #000, #AA0000);  
}
hr.separator.blue{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0000AA, #000, #0000AA);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0000AA, #000, #0000AA);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #0000AA, #000, #0000AA);
    background-image: -o-lineargradient(left, #0000AA, #000, #0000AA);  
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator red" />
<hr class="separator blue" />
```

Comment: Great answer~ actually I have been pondering how to add some more. Thank you so much.

Comment: ur welcome. in CSS world always try to separate color from size and those from position in terms of class names